# SVG in Firefox available to draw only on small area

Tags: firefox, svg

everyone!
Please help me to solve a problem. I have the following svg:

```
    <div style="height: 1257px; width: 728px;">
        <svg viewPort="0 0 728 1257" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" y2="100" x2="100" y1="100" x1="20"/>
            <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" y2="150" x2="200" y1="154" x1="504"/>
            <line y2="353" x2="504" y1="459" x1="388" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
            <line y2="353" x2="504" y1="400" x1="1141" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
            <line y2="197" x2="602" y1="353" x1="504" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
            <line y2="371" x2="957" y1="274" x1="749" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
            <line y2="192" x2="1079" y1="371" x1="957" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Please, check it in the FF: http://jsfiddle.net/SgAA5/.

It contains 7 lines inside. I can see it correctly in all browsers except Firefox. Whats wrong with this svg? I trying to draw lines through different ways, but I see only following in the FF:

[image]

Just one line, and the part of another one. Looks like only small area available to draw. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline SVG with transforms not visible in Firefox, works fine in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769006/inline-svg-with-transforms-not-visible-in-firefox-works-fine-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found solution on stackoverflow :) [Inline SVG with transforms not visible in Firefox, works fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769006/inline-svg-with-transforms-not-visible-in-firefox-works-fine-in-chrome?rq=1)
It depends on tag parameters.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
```

is right way